Update TFS 2018 server (on premises) to AzDevOps 2022 server (on premises)
TF255156: Azure DevOps Server does not support multi-server installation unless the servers are part of an Active Directory domain. Only single-server installation is supported in a workgroup environment.
TF255507: The security identifier (SID) for the following SQL Server login conflicts with a specified domain or workgroup account: B****\Administrator. The domain or workgroup account is: AZ***\Administrator.  The server selected to host the databases for Azure DevOps Server is: B****.

You can resolve this issue by renaming the conflicting login. To do so, open a command prompt on the computer that is running SQL Server and execute the following command:
sqlcmd -E -S "B****" -Q "ALTER LOGIN [B****\Administrator] WITH NAME = [AZ***\Administrator]"
I am Updating  TFS 2018 server (on premises) to AzDevOps 2022 server (on premises) while I got this error.

Have you tried the command mentioned in the error message?

Yes, but not executable. Tried In both servers.

What steps/configurations have you done before getting the error?

I am using previously TFS 2018 on premises to upgrade to a AzDevOps 2022 on premises, on Hyper-V created servers, on dry test on installation of console of AzDevOps. “ I need a domain for the two servers” I was connecting the SQL server through LAN

One server host name Bal and other one AzDev

Do you try to install AzDevOps 2022 on the same machine with TFS 2018?

Yes, I have no issue, install in same machine

Reference "Requirements for Azure DevOps on-premises", ensure you have first updated the SQL Server to the supported version for Azure DevOps Server 2022. Then try to uninstall the old TFS 2018 application and install the latest Azure DevOps Server 2022 application.

As stated in my answer below, if you try to install Azure DevOps Server 2022 on the same server machine, you need to first uninstall the old TFS 2018 application, then install the Azure DevOps Server 2022. Have tried this, and does this work for you? @BallaBobby

You can do like as one of the following ways:

If you want to install Azure DevOps Server 2022 on the same machine that the old TFS 2018 is hosted.

Uninstall the old TFS 2018 application.
Updated SQL Server to the supported version for Azure DevOps Server 2022. Also ensure other requirements are satisfied. See "Requirements for Azure DevOps on-premises".
Download and install the latest version of Azure DevOps Server 2022.


If you do not want to uninstall the old TFS 2018, you need to install the Azure DevOps Server 2022 on another machine.

Install the supported version for Azure DevOps Server 2022 on the machine. Also ensure other requirements are satisfied.
Download and install the latest version of Azure DevOps Server 2022 on the machine.
Move the data from TFS 2018 to Azure DevOps Server 2022. See "Move project collection".




